# Article "the" before the phrase "coolness criteria"

Tags: definite-article

Tell me please why "the" was used before "coolness criteria", even though it had not been mentioned before by the author. Here is the context:

> Being regarded as cool is something that you might desire, but is this a quality you really have control over? University of Sydney psychologists Ilan Dar-Nimrod and colleagues put **the** coolness criteria to the test in their study of the traits that contribute to this seemingly desirable has out.

Have the author put "the" because he thinks the readers know what kind of criteria he is talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is talking about all criteria that control whether a person is regarded as cool. In that sense they have specified which 'coolness criteria' they are talking about, even though as readers we don't know what kind of criteria they are.

It's similar to if I say "I ate some sandwiches. **The** sandwiches were disgusting." You don't what kind of sandwiches they were, but I use *the* because you know which sandwiches I'm talking about - the ones that I ate.

Comment: So if the author had dropped "the" , then It would mean that  not all but some coolness criteria was put to the test,  am I right?

Comment: Yes, it could mean that, or it could mean that the author isn't interested in whether or not all the coolness criteria were tested.